# Cant INSERT INTO database with PHP, No errors thrown

Tags: php, mysql, sql-insert

Okay so I am using PHP and I need the contents of a text box to be put into the table of my DB and when I click submit not errors are thrown but nothing is put in the DB here is my code:

**HTML:**

```
<html>
<title>Chat App</title>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="chatCSS.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="logOut">
        <form action="loggedOut.php" method="POST">
            <input type="submit" value="Log Out">
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="incomeMessages">
        <input type="text" id="incomeMessageBox" disabled="disabled">
        <br>
        <br>
        <form method="POST" action="index.php">
            <input type="text" name="message" id="myMessage" placeholder="Message here...">
            <input type="submit" id="myMessageSubmit">
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**PHP:**

```
<?php
require 'includes/connect_mysql.php';
require 'includes/sessionCheck.php';

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    $message = $_POST['message'];
    $time = time();
    $user = $_SESSION['activeUser'];

    if ($db_connect) {
        $SQL = "INSERT INTO mainconversation (Name, Message, Time) VALUES ('$user', '$message', '$time')";

        $result = mysqli_query($connection, $SQL);
        mysqli_close($connection);
    }

}

?>
```

**CONNECTION CODE:**

```
<?PHP

$db_host = "localhost"; 

$db_username = "xxxx";  

$db_pass = "xxxxxxxx";  

$db_name = "chatapp"; 


$connection = mysqli_connect("$db_host","$db_username","$db_pass") or die ("could not connect to mysql");
$db_connect = mysqli_select_db($connection, "$db_name") or die ("no database");  

?>
```

Comment: *"No errors thrown"* - Are you checking for errors? If not, add error reporting to the top of your file(s) 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` see if it yields anything. Plus, you do have `session_start();` loaded, right?

Comment: This `$result = mysqli_query($connection, $SQL);` should most likely be `$result = mysqli_query($db_connect, $SQL);` hard to say without knowing what your DB connection variable is.

Comment: `mysqli_query($connection, $SQL);` is the wrong way to use `mysqli`, use it in an object oriented style instead. with `$conn = new mysqli()` ... `$conn->query("...");`

Comment: while you are at it, also consider that your code is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. Please read about how to use prepared statements.

Comment: also add `or die( mysql_error())` after mysql_query like `$query = mysql_query("select id, email = '$email' and password='$password'") or die( mysql_error());`

Comment: @bhushya OP is using `mysqli_` and not `mysql_`

Comment: yo I missed that :), but logic still same..

Comment: yes i know i am not using it in an object oriented way and thank you for the reminder of injections

Comment: Show us what's inside `connect_mysql.php` - which is most likely the place where the errors are.

Comment: Change `if ($db_connect) {` to `if ($connection) {` and get rid of `$db_connect = mysqli_select_db($connection, "$db_name") or die ("no database");` while changing it to `$connection = mysqli_connect("$db_host","$db_username","$db_pass","$db_name")`

Comment: i did change it and same issue

Comment: I edited [`my comment`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24871929/cant-insert-into-database-with-php-no-errors-thrown#comment38629581_24871929) above, reload it. That should fix it.

Comment: Or do `$connection = mysqli_connect($db_host,$db_username,$db_pass,$db_name)` without the quotes.

Comment: the way it is now connects to the database just fine, if i add an echo alert inside the if (db_connect) then it works

Comment: Did you add the error reporting codes I've given you in my first comment?

Comment: if i get rid of the variables in the SQL statement and hard code values, then it works, and no i didn't but i added a `die` statement which is giving me my errors

Comment: I noticed you have 2 forms. Which one are you using to submit with?

Comment: the form that has the action `index.php`

Comment: I suggest then, that you change `<input type="submit" id="myMessageSubmit">` to `<input type="submit" id="myMessageSubmit" name="message_submit">` and to work with that, change `if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){` to `if(isset($_POST['message_submit'])){` see if that makes it kick into gear. I can't see what else would make this fail.

Comment: i think I've found it, it doesn't like my variables, if i try to do an `alert()` with the `$user` or `$time` variable it won't work. but if i do it with the `$message` one it pops up just fine

Comment: got it, the `$user` variable already contained `' '` around it so when i put them around the variable in the SQL it took it as `" "`

Comment: Problem solved then, great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

got it, the `$user` variable already contained `' '` around it so when i put them around the variable in the SQL it took it as `" "`

Thanks for all the help!!!

Comment: I'm glad you made it work :)

Answer (score 3):

You are not checking for errors, try changing your line $result like this:

```
$result = mysqli_query($connection,$SQL) or die(mysqli_error($connection));
```

You will then get the errors if there are some.

Comment: i did this and it says i have an error in my sql statement, not sure where that is though

Comment: @Darksaint2014 - that's your cue to post the error message...

Comment: Please copy/paste the whole error message here

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'admin'', 'test', '1405966950')' at line 1

Comment: @Darksaint2014 Seems like you're probably using `mysql_` based connection, where there's only 3 parameters, or you're missing something, or bad quotes etc. hard to say till we see full code for DB connection. Post your DB connection codes in your question, while replacing credentials with `xxx`

Comment: I can see 'test' and '1405966950' are using single quotes but your admin is between both single and double quote 'admin". Please check your syntax

Comment: I'm not sure what would cause that because in the sql code they are all in single quotes